# Tmux + urxvt ghost activity notifications

Tags: zsh, tmux, urxvt

Im using tmux on urxvt, I have activity monitoring turned on and i noticed that all tmux windows get an activity notification after every 10~15 seconds, when i switch to that window there is nothing. It could be something in my zsh config (I use oh-my-zsh) is there any way identify what causes the activity ?

BTW: Im using nested tmux sessions.
here are my configs:

https://github.com/jagguli/dotfiles/blob/master/.tmux.conf

https://github.com/jagguli/dotfiles/blob/master/.tmux_outer.conf

Answer (score 0):

Did you by any chance include the seconds in the clock in your tmux status bar? Tmux will update your status bar every 15 seconds, which would trigger the activity notification.

Edit: Instead of

```
set-option -g status-right '#[fg=green]#(date +"%h %a %d %H:%M") #[fg=white]#(whoami)@#h'
```

try

```
set-option -g status-right '#[fg=green]%h %a %d %H:%M #[fg=white]#(whoami)@#h'
```

to use `tmux`'s built-in `strftime`-processing of `status-right` instead of calling `date`. `tmux` will call any external commands every 15 minutes by default, and I bet it doesn't check to see if the new output is the same as the current display, and so writes the "new" string to the screen, triggering an activity alert.

Comment: I thought it might be because of that, but nope no clock in my status. But it might be because of that as i'm using nested tmux, maybe the inner tmux is triggering an clock event ??

Answer (score 0):

It's the nested [tmux](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1)'s status clock which triggers the notifications. You can prevent this by setting the `status-interval` option to a high value that suits your needs *(eg. 43200 for 12 hours)*, or 0 to disable if you use [tmux](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi/OpenBSD-current/man1/tmux.1?query=tmux&sec=1) version 1.9 or above.

For more details have a look at [my answer to this other question on the subject](https://superuser.com/a/813135/200529).